# Can we change PowerShell sessions's LanguageMode?

Tags: powershell

My current environment is Windows 7 Enterprise Edition(SP1) with PowerShell V5

PSVersion = 5.0.10586.117

For somehow when I try to run the following statement (it worked well before)

```
new-object System.Net.WebClient
```

I started to get the following error

[image: Cannot create type. Only core types are supported in this language mode]

I checked

```
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode
```

and the result is: **ConstrainedLanguage**

I am now at a loss on how to change this LanguageMode to "FullLanguage" as mentioned in this [URL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn433292.aspx)

I googled around and do not see anything related to my environment, the closest link I see is [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/44445864-ee91-4073-9f21-50ab36ec781b/powershell-5-limited-to-constrainedlanguage-language-mode?forum=winserverpowershell) in MS technet forum. But in my case, I do not think it is AppLocker enabled (or do I have to ask my network admin to check the group policy?) and I do not see any SRP (Software Restriction Policy) on my local computer either.

Could someone please tell me how to fix this issue or how to check various aspects that lead to this LanguageMode change? or is there a way that I can edit the LangugageMode value? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `Get-Help 'about_Session_Configuration_Files' -ShowWindow` could help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after numerous attempts, I finally figured out why. I updated my WMF 5.0 production preview to the WMF 5.0 Production RTM about 10 days ago, but since then, I have not run any scripts including

```
new-object System.Net.WebClient
```

and as such, I never encountered the error mentioned.

After I uninstalled this WMF 5.0 Prod RTM version, I am now in PS Version 4.

PSVersion = 4.0

and when I run

```
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode
```

I get "FullLanguage" value as shown below

[image: LanguageMode of PS Session]

So I think it is kind of a bug for WMF 5.0 to Windows 7.0, and MS should fix it.

I checked my computer with Win 10 OS and WMF 5.0 RTM, the LanguageMode is still "FullLanguage".

**[Edit]: 2016.Nov.25**

I think I need to update this answer by saying that since the error occurred and I downgraded to V4, it solved the problem, **but** probably another two weeks later, I reinstalled WMF 5.0 (I believe the downloaded file is different from my initial downloaded file as the download link are different), now this solves the problem as well, i.e. in PS V5.0, the error does not appear again.Here is my current environment

[image]

Answer (score -2):

To change the languagemode you can just use the variable:

```
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode = "FullLanguage"
```

Comment: If you are in `ConstrainedLanguage` mode, you are not allowed to execute this command.